# Localhost HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: server, apache2, php, xampp

I have problem that when I add  to my page index.php it says This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Before this problem I had a problem with port. I just changed port 80 to 8080

I am using Xampp. Here is log from Xampp Apache2:

```
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.168107 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 74410] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.168156 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 74410] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.194898 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 74411] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.194914 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 74411] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.194983 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 74411] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.202714 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 74411] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1i PHP/8.0.1 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 24 16:21:54.202780 2021] [core:notice] [pid 74411] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you need to run SSL on a local installation?

Comment: No I don't need SSL.